# Proper Symfony Package to Consume and Provide API via REST

Tags: symfony

I need to create a middleware app that provides an api and consumes two apis. However, I am having a problem with two Symfony packages: [HTTP Client](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html) and [HttpFoundation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html)

I don't understand when I should be using one versus the other. Little new to Symfony and I've read the docs but they both allow for you to consume and provide and api vis request and response methods or classes depending on which package you use.

I know I'm missing something obvious but I'm having a hard time of it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have to use `The HttpFoundation Component`. It is easy to use in your Symfony application controller too. i.e

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
* @Route("/api/product/list", name="api_product_list", methods={"GET"})
* @param Request $request
* @return Response
*/
public function getList(Request $request): Response
{
   $product = $request->get('product');
   
   return $this->json(['product' => $product]);
}
```

More information about [HTTPFoundation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html) you already know.